# Can i use Requirejs in onepage simple html website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, requirejs

I have a one-page landing page for the service based company. 
I want to make it fast loading for a one-page website. 
Can I use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) for it? if not then is there any way to load 
one-page website in 3 secs?

Thank you

Comment: Requirejs won't have much to do with your loading speed. Other than that, of course you can use it for single page apps.

Comment: I have just one page HTML landing page

Comment: How much javascript code do you have?

Comment: _"is there any way to load one-page website in 3 secs?"_ ... if the content size and network speed allows it, yes, if not, no.

Comment: @FranjoPintarić I use more than 3 js libraries and analytics js.

Comment: you can load a website larger than yours but using AMP. BTW, if you're not, and it's loading in more than 3 or 4 seconds, check your hosting network speed and bandwidth, and inspect networking load with F12 on your browser. Usually putting your JS libs inside your server instead of loading it from third-party CDN is faster and can give you a second less as benefit. Then, minify your js and your CSS.